# How do I write a function with the signature `(Proxy a -> s) -> Proxy (Maybe a) -> Maybe s`

Tags: haskell

As per the title, I'm looking to write a function with the following signature.

```
g :: (Proxy a -> s) -> Proxy (Maybe a) -> Maybe s
g f x = ...
```

For my use case, `f` is `symbolVal`. I can run `symbolVal` on a plain `KnownSymbol a => a`, but I can't get this to work on `KnownSymbol a => Maybe a`.

Comment: I am *beyond confused* as to what this question means. `g f x = Just $ f Proxy` fits, but this is trivial; it doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: I have changed "`g` is `symbolVal`" to "`f` is `symbolVal`" because I can't understand that paragraph otherwise. If that change was incorrect, please feel free to roll it back -- but consider this a request to add a bit more text there to explain what you mean when you do.

Comment: What is `KnownSymbol a => Maybe a`? Naively, that looks ill-kinded; `KnownSymbol` takes a `Symbol`, but `Maybe` takes a `Type`. Is there something very odd going on with `DataKinds` here? If so, show some more code so we can see it. If not, then what does this mean?

Answer (score 5):

Up to isomorphism, a type `Proxy T` is equal to `()` -- indeed both types only have one possible values.

Also, up to isomorphism, a function `() -> T` is equal to `T` -- after all the function can only be called with one value.

One can then simplify (up to isomorphism) your type as follows:

```
(Proxy a -> s) -> Proxy (Maybe a) -> Maybe s
~=
(() -> s) -> () -> Maybe s
~=
s -> Maybe s
```

Hence, your question is equivalent to "how can we implement `s -> Maybe s` and we only have two ways t do that:

```
f x = Just x
f x = Nothing
```

Translating back to your `g` we obtain the two solutions

```
g h _ = Just (h Proxy)
g h _ = Nothing
```

I don't think either of these is interesting, but there are no other (terminating) choices.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378): you're asking about a different problem from what you really should be solving.

See, proxies were always just a hack to make up for the fact that Haskell isn't really designed to pass around type information like you can pass around values. (By contrast, dependently typed languages are designed up-front for doing this.) But actually, for quite a while now Haskell *has* included a feature that allows explicitly passing types: `-XTypeApplications`. So at this point proxies are basically just a legacy alternative, but in your own code I would suggest not worrying about how you can manipulate proxies or proxy-functions. Instead you should just pass around the type information explicitly, and if you need to fulfill the `Proxy whvr ->` argument of some library function then simply give it `Proxy @whvr` right there and then.

If you don't understand how to do that, give a bit more example code of the use-case in which you really have this need.

Comment: Last I checked, proxies (or `Tagged`) were still needed in higher rank applications.

Comment: @dfeuer sometimes that is easier than doing it with local bindings + ScopedTypeVariables + TypeApplications, yes. But IMO in those cases it's usually best to introduce a suitable GADT or something else that has the capabilities of proxies as well as better expressing the intention.